# Font scaling different per page

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am building a website with a mobile and normal version. The normal version works fine, however, the mobile version has a strange issue. The font size is different per page, so, for instance, I defined *h3* to be 48px. Now on one page this works perfectly fine however on a different page the 48px is scaled 59.5556px. This also happens *a*, *p* and every other header type, which results in the text looking big on one page and barely readable on the other page. All the css for every page is exactly the same. I cannot link the website since it is still in development.

Examples:

[normal font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rucwU.png)

[scaled font size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWl37.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this meta tag in your head section to prevent the mobile doing it's own scaling.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: If I add that the size of the text is the same however all my elements for which I specified a width of 100% appear to be only half of the full width.

Comment: Sorry it is hard to tell without seeing your code. However that meta tag must be used for a responsive site to display properly. So there must be an issue with your HTML or CSS.